# Web services - front end or logic

Tags: web-services

Which one should be developed first - front end or the main logic, in terms of efficiency and ease? I want to develop a web service.

Comment: Why does there need to be a "first?"

Comment: Yeah, I realize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not common but if you know what you are going to program in the logic, I recommend to build the logic first. Otherwise, I recommend you to start with the views and the logic part can be built from it.

Usually, in a big project you have to think about every part of it before you start coding, but for practice, it is fine.